# State space search for sliding tile puzzle

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am working on **state space search** (8 Puzzle) in Python and when I run my program with `python3 -m profile`, I find out that most of time program performs a few functions. I would like to optimize functions bellow (if it's possible).

I am using dictionary `node`, whose structure is:

```
{
    'id': string,  # Unique ID of node, e. g. '123456708'.
    'state': array,  # Numpy array 3x3 with unique numbers 1-8 and 0, e. g. [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 0 8]].
    'pos': tuple,  # Current position of 0 in node's state, e. g. (2, 1).
}
```

### swap

Function accepts 2D `array`, `pos1` and `pos2` and returns new array with swapped elements on positions.

```
# [1 2 3]                            [0 2 3]
# [4 5 6] -> swap((2, 1), (0, 0)) -> [4 5 6]
# [7 0 8]                            [7 1 8]
def swap(array, pos1, pos2):
    result = numpy.copy(array)
    result[pos1], result[pos2] = result[pos2], result[pos1]
    return result
```

### create

Function that accepts `state` and `pos` of `0` in state and returns node with this state.

```
def create(state, pos):
    return { 'id': hash(state.tostring()), 'state': state, 'pos': pos }
```

### move

Function, that accepts `node` and vector `change` and returns new node with changed state. New state is created when `0` in state is moved by vector (changeY, changeX) `change`. If new state has invalid index, return `None` instead.

```
# [1 2 3]                   [1 2 3]
# [4 5 6] -> move(-1, 0) -> [4 0 6]
# [7 0 8]                   [7 5 8]
def move(node, change):
    newPos = (node['pos'][0] + change[0], node['pos'][1] + change[1]) # numpy.add(node['pos'], change) is slower.

    if 0 <= newPos[0] <= 2 and 0 <= newPos[1] <= 2: # Valid index
        newState = swap(node['state'], node['pos'], newPos)
        return create(newState, newPos)

    return None # Invalid index.
```

### getSuccessors

Function that accepts `node` in state and returns all nodes which state is about -1 or 1 different vertically or horizontally (not both):

```
# [1 2 3]                       [1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]
# [4 5 6] -> getSuccessors() -> [4 0 6] [4 5 6] [4 5 6]
# [7 0 8]                       [7 5 8] [0 7 8] [7 8 0]
def getSuccessors(node):
    moves = [
        move(node, (-1, 0)),
        move(node, (1, 0)),
        move(node, (0, -1)),
        move(node, (0, 1)),
    ]

    return list(filter(lambda node: node is not None, moves))
```

### findPath

Function accepts numpy 3x3 arrays `init` and `goal` and search successors of `init` until one of successors will be `goal`.

```
def findPath(init, goal):
    explored = {} # Already explored nodes.
    pos = numpy.where(init == 0)
    unexplored = [create(init, (pos[0][0], pos[1][0]))] # Unexplored nodes.

    while True:
        if not unexplored: # If there is no node to explore, puzzle has no solution.
            return None

        node = unexplored.pop(0) # Bfs algorithm is slow, but for testing purposes.

        if numpy.array_equal(node['state'], goal):
            return 'Success' # Should be path, but for now is not important.

        explored[node['id']] = node

        for successor in getSuccessors(node): # Add successors to unexplored nodes.
            if successor['id'] not in explored:
                unexplored.append(successor)
```

When I run this program `python3 puzzle.py`, it takes 13.36 seconds:

```
import time
import numpy
start = time.time()
init = numpy.array([[7, 2, 4], [5, 0, 6], [8, 3, 1]])
goal = numpy.array([[1, 3, 0], [5, 2, 6], [4, 7, 8]])
print(findPath(init, goal)) # 'Success'
end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 13.36 s
```

With `python3 -m profile puzzle.py | grep "puzzle.py"`:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   52.771   52.771 profile:0(<code object <module> at 0x7fa52c125300, file "puzzle.py", line 1>)
        1    0.131    0.131   52.752   52.752 puzzle.py:1(<module>)
  1638628    6.305    0.000   25.991    0.000 puzzle.py:12(move)
   409657    4.410    0.000   31.730    0.000 puzzle.py:21(getSuccessors)
  1638628    1.330    0.000    1.330    0.000 puzzle.py:29(<lambda>)
        1    3.066    3.066   52.195   52.195 puzzle.py:31(findPath)
  1106988    3.519    0.000   14.525    0.000 puzzle.py:4(swap)
  1106989    3.049    0.000    5.161    0.000 puzzle.py:9(create)
```

Most of the time was `move` executed (6.3 s), then `getSuccessors` (4.4 s), `swap`, `findPath` and `create`. Is there any way to optimize these functions? [Here](https://repl.it/repls/WigglyExtralargeAssembly) is the whole program (even slower than on my PC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial approach definitely has a number of "bottlenecks" and space for optimizations.
Let me present and explain the crucial points:

- starting with good naming: don't give Python identifiers/functions *camelCased* names. We'll have `find_path`, `get_successors` etc.
- `explored` dict accumulates a great number of dictionaries (`nodes`) indexed by their `id` attribute (*"hash"*). But those dictionaries are not used, only keys are used to keep track of processing unique `id`s (*hashes*). Memory-free solution for this point is using `set` instead to keep unique hashes. `explored = set()`
- `unexplored` list. At the end of the processing I noticed it grown to size of `53003`. As the main operations on this list are appending to and popping out the 1st item - the optimized way would be to use a high-performance [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object (Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same `O(1)` performance in either direction)
- function `move` performs a lot of *falsy* calls (returning `None`). That makes the caller `get_successors` accumulate both valid and *falsy* movements (`moves` list) and perform filtration on each call. Instead, we'll make `get_successors` to work as generator function which yields only successfully moved nodes (after *valid* movements)
- looping over `for successor in getSuccessors(node):` performs a hundreds of redundant iterations testing *successors*(nodes) which hashes were already present in `explored` *hash* storage. To watch that happened you can add `else:` branch with debugging printing to `if successor['id'] not in explored: ...` condition within the loop. 
  To avoid that, in connection to the previous Optimization tip, we'll extend `get_successors` function more to get correctly moved nodes that aren't present in `explored` hash-set.

---

From theory to practice:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import deque


def swap(array, pos1, pos2):
    result = np.copy(array)
    result[pos1], result[pos2] = result[pos2], result[pos1]
    return result


def create(state, pos):
    return {'id': hash(state.tostring()), 'state': state, 'pos': pos}


def move(node, change):
    new_pos = (node['pos'][0] + change[0], node['pos'][1] + change[1])  # np.add(node['pos'], change) is slower.

    if 0 <= new_pos[0] <= 2 and 0 <= new_pos[1] <= 2:  # Valid index
        new_state = swap(node['state'], node['pos'], new_pos)
        return create(new_state, new_pos)


def get_successors(node, explored):
    for new_pos in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
        changed_node = move(node, new_pos)
        if changed_node and changed_node['id'] not in explored:
            yield changed_node


def find_path(init, goal):
    explored = set()  # Already explored nodes.
    pos = np.where(init == 0)
    unexplored = deque([create(init, (pos[0][0], pos[1][0]))])  # Unexplored nodes.

    while True:
        if not unexplored:  # If there is no node to explore, puzzle has no solution.
            return None

        node = unexplored.popleft()

        if np.array_equal(node['state'], goal):
            return 'Success'  # Should be path, but for now is not important.

        explored.add(node['id'])

        for successor in get_successors(node, explored):  # Add successors to unexplored nodes.
            unexplored.append(successor)


start = time.time()
init = np.array([[7, 2, 4], [5, 0, 6], [8, 3, 1]])
goal = np.array([[1, 3, 0], [5, 2, 6], [4, 7, 8]])

print(find_path(init, goal))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

The output:

```
Success
5.768321752548218
```

Comment: Thanks for useful hints and explanation. The program is now really 2 times faster.

Comment: @Michal, you're welcome